# How to slow down iMac CPU for quiet operation

Tags: imac, cpu, power-management

With the help of Turbo Boost Switcher Pro, I could always keep my iMac 2020 with its 8-core i7 fanless for 99% of the time without any noticeable slowdown on daily work.

Until now. However, now it gets warmer (and there's no air conditioning ), it starts using its fans even when idling.

Is there a trick or tool to slow down the CPU further to reduce heat and fan noise? The CPU power would probably still be more than enough for daily usage.

Comment: Why did you buy the 8-core i7, which gets much hotter than the 6-core i5? Why is running the fan a problem? Noise in audio studio? If you want cool and fanless, get an M1.

Comment: If the ambient temperature rises, then it needs to work harder to cool the processor. It was ok during the winter when the ambient temperature was lower, right? So your answer is to lower the ambient temperature.

Comment: Portable air con is going to make at least as much noise as the iMac fan: you might as well just have the fan. (To say nothing of energy usage/climate concerns.)

Comment: iMacs collect quite some dust over time. May be worth cleaning the ventilation openings to improve airflow.

Comment: Unless your computer is in a very dusty or dirty environment, it shouldn't need a clean out just yet. However, you can download fan control software and manage the fan yourself. The CPU is designed to thermal throttle before it gets too hot.